# Entity Framework - unwanted population of related entity

Tags: entity-framework

Given

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public bool IsSubscribed { get; set; }
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set;}
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
        }
```

why does

```
onDb = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
```

populate the MembershipType object??? I don't want that to happen.

Is it because I have loaded the customer with the same ID before?

Comment: You have loaded the `MembershipType` object before.

Comment: Not using this context ...

Comment: Well, you must have. If not directly, then indirectly by loading the customer including its `MembershipType`. Check `context.Set<MembershipType>().Local`.

Comment: I would agree with you, but I can't see where. I must have... I'll look again.

Comment: It can't be lazy loading (the property isn't virtual), so it must have been eager/explicit loading.

Comment: I found somewhere where I had loaded _context.MembershipTypes by itself, that must have been it: Thanks!